# Easiest way to fetch all href contents on page in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, regex, parsing, html-parsing

I'm writing a simple web crawler in Ruby and I need to fetch all `href` contents on the page. What is the best way to do this, or any other web page source parsing, since some pages might not be valid, but I still want to be able to parse them.

Are there any good Ruby HTML parsers that allow *validity agnostic* parsing, or is the best way just to do it by hand with regexp?

Is it possible to use XPath on non-XHTML page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).  Short example:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.com/search?q=tenderlove'))
doc.search('//*[@href]').each do |m| p m[:href] end
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/WWW/Mechanize.html).  I'm pretty sure it has methods for grabbing all links in a page.